# How many solutions are there to an $n$ by $n$ queens problem?

Tags: permutations, combinations

Is there a way to calculate the number of solutions to $n$ by $n$ queen problem(done by backtracking) or it's complex and already defined as in the following table

[image]

Comment: [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000170) is a good friend for references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment, if you already know this many terms of a sequence, you can usually find most of what's known about it at OEIS.

The number of solutions is [OEIS sequence A000170](http://oeis.org/A000170).

The number of equivalence classes of solutions under isometries is [OEIS sequence A002562](https://oeis.org/A002562).

Neither entry provides a closed form, recurrence or generating function.